# Dissolve lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I have following lambda calculus:

```
(λx. + (- x 1)) 9 3
```

The right beta reduce is:

```
+ (- 9 1) 3
```

I made a mistake and took instead of 9 the number 3:

```
+ (- 3 1) 9
```

and I've got the same result.

I wasn't realize that was wrong, until compare it with the solution.

Do I have to take the closest substitution, in this case is 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact you got the same answer in this arithmetic example is a coincidence caused by the arithmetic rather than the lambda calculus.

If you wrote more spaces to make the term structure clearer, it would be easier to see what's going on

```
(\x. + (- x 1)) 9 3
```

means, with gratuitous extra parentheses showing the parse tree,

```
((\x. (+ (- x 1))) 9) 3
```

because **application associates to the left** ("rather as we all did in the sixties" - Roger Hindley).

So, the 3 is in the wrong place to be substituted for the x. We have only

```
( (\x. (+ (- x 1))) 9 ) 3
  =
(+ (- 9 1)) 3
  =
(+ 8) 3
  =
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you always need to apply a lambda to its "first" (leftmost) argument.

In theory, there is not such a thing as multiple arguments, there is only application of a single argument. Still, it is common to write
`f M N O` for the repeated application `(((f M) N) O)`. Note how `f` takes `M` as its argument.

In the general case, you will not get the same result if you do application in a different order. Your example was only an incident.